# apt commands doesn't work

Tags: apt

apt already worked fine. but in order to solving package not found error I used bellow commands

```
sudo sed -i -e s/universe//g /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i -e s/main/"main universe"/ /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And now whenever I use any of apt commands I face this error

```
  $ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 15 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Is there any solution??!

Comment: The first step would be to look at entry #15 in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Apparently your brave approach of editing the file in-place without making a backup has fuzzed the file.